# Export problems with Kartik's gridview loaded with ExpandRowColumn

Tags: gridview, yii2, kartik-v

I'm rendering a [Kartik's Gridview](http://demos.krajee.com/grid) which loads another Gridview via ajax by [ExpandRowColumn](http://demos.krajee.com/grid#expand-row-column) widget.

I'd like to export this secondary loaded grid using grid tools, but when I enable the export menu and try exporting it it will download the *main* grid and not the second one. Even the export configuration options I set on the second grid are not taken into account. I tried setting a custom `id` for the second grid but didn't change anything.

This is the first grid:

```

```
GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => false,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'class' => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
                'value' => function ($model, $key, $index) { 
                    return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
                },
                'detailUrl' => Url::to(['ajax-riepilogo', 'idf' => $f]),
            ],
            'descrizione',
        ],
    ]);
```

```

And this is the one being generated in `ajax-riepilogo`:

```

```
GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $secondDataProvider,
        'id' => 'grid-riepilogo',
        'panel' => [
            'type' => 'primary',
            'heading' => false,
        ],
        'toolbar' => ['{export}'],
        'export' => [
            'showConfirmAlert' => false,
            'target' => GridView::TARGET_BLANK,
            'exportConfig' => [
                GridView::CSV => [
                    'filename' => "riepilogo',
                ],
                GridView::EXCEL => [
                    'filename' => "riepilogo',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'summary' => false,
        'filterModel' => false,
        'columns' => [
           ...
```

```

Comment: Try adding `options => ['id' => 'unique_id']`  in export of both gridview.

Comment: Actually it's just `'id'  => 'unique_id'`, and seems to work by just setting it into the inner table because the exported data is relative to that. It's still not considiering the file name customization, but it might be a config problem

Comment: That solved your export problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors:

1. the `id` must be unique for every grid in the page
2. the `exportConfig` config attribute needs to be at *top level*

Working config:

```
     GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $secondDataProvider,
    'id' => 'grid-riepilogo-'.$unique,
    'panel' => [
        'type' => 'primary',
        'heading' => false,
    ],
    'toolbar' => ['{export}'],
    'export' => [
        'showConfirmAlert' => false,
        'target' => GridView::TARGET_BLANK,
    ],
    'exportConfig' => [
        GridView::CSV => [
            'filename' => "riepilogo',
        ],
        GridView::EXCEL => [
            'filename' => "riepilogo',
        ],
    ],
    'summary' => false,
    'filterModel' => false,
    'columns' => [
       ...
```